# Why object_id changes after app initialization?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autoload, zeitwerk

Rails 6.1.4.1

I'm setting values from an initializer file and when I request a page, I find the `object_id` of the configuration changed (and the values lost) unless I do `require 'my_library'` in the initializer file. I don't understand why?

app/lib/feature_flags.rb:

```rb
class FeatureFlags
  class Configuration
    include ActiveSupport::Configurable

    config_accessor(:my_key) { false }
  end

  class << self
    def configuration
      @configuration ||= Configuration.new
    end

    def configure
      yield configuration
    end

    def enabled?(feature)
      puts "#{__FILE__} FeatureFlags.configuration.object_id = #{FeatureFlags.configuration.object_id}"

      configuration[feature]
    end
  end
end
```

config/initializers/feature_flags.rb:

```rb
# require 'feature_flag' # If I uncomment this line, the problem is solved

puts "#{__FILE__} FeatureFlags.configuration.object_id = #{FeatureFlags.configuration.object_id}"

FeatureFlags.configure do |config|
  config.my_key = true
end
```

Output:

```
1. Run the rails server:
config/initializers/feature_flags.rb FeatureFlags.configuration.object_id = 14720

2. Request some page:
app/lib/feature_flags.rb FeatureFlags.configuration.object_id = 22880
```

My questions are:

- Why do I need to `require 'feature_flags'` in the initializer for the object_id not to change? I thought Zeitwerk was taking care of this.
- Is that how I'm supposed to do (to do it right)?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You could make your class a [`Singleton`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/singleton/rdoc/Singleton.html) *"This ensures that only one instance of Klass can be created"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my answer here: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#use-case-1-during-boot-load-reloadable-code

**Why is it not working:** because FeatureFlags is a reloadable class, it is replaced by a new object uppon request.

**How am I supposed to do it right:** wrap my initialization code in a `to_prepare` block:

```rb
Rails.application.config.to_prepare do
  FeatureFlags.configure do |config|
    config.my_key = true
  end
end
```